EXCEPTION ERROR C06D007E Error in Automation Studio
My project I created using B&R Automation Studio was working yesterday, this morning I turned on my computer and deleted only WireShark and Realterm programs and deleted unnecessary files using windows pc manager. After that, when I opened my project, I started getting this error all the time and I don't know how to solve it.


if you have Microsoft Access Database Engine installed, try to uninstall it and reinstall it from here : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920
